# powershell object sort descending

Tags: powershell, sorting

this powershell stuff

```
$Processes = get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName
foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
    $Obj = New-Object psobject
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Process.Name
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Mem -Value ($Process.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum
    $Obj | sort Mem -Descending
}
```

outputs the same as this

```
$Processes = get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName
foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
    $Obj = New-Object psobject
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Process.Name
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Mem -Value ($Process.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum
    $Obj
}
```

I'm not well enough versed to know if it is in fact working but because the items are summed then it was ordered off of the first value, but because it is still sorted alphabetically I think it just isn't set to the correct value to sort. I have tried these in several different combinations

sort, sort-object, sort-object -property "Mem" -Descending, Mem, "Mem", WS, "WS", WorkingSet, @{Expression="Mem"; Descending=$true} and various permutations,

throwing the resulting  $Obj to another sorted $Obj(that threw an error saying it didn't have addition $ObjS += $obj |sort etc) several other methods of calling sort on object that I didn't save or remember.

and have come to the conclusion that my error likely stems from someplace else however because of no errors being thrown I believe that my syntax is correct at least.

I'd like the output to be sorted by the memory usage of the processes (combined by same name to get total memory of similar processes,

ie all of chromes processes as just one --chrome  1650453708--

also this is on whatever powershell is with windows 7 if that helps at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the data set then sort.

```
Function Get-ProcessMemorySummary1
{
    $Processes = Get-Process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName
    foreach($Process in $Processes)
    {
        $Obj = New-Object psobject
        $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Process.Name
        $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Mem -Value ($Process.Group `
             | Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum
        $Obj | sort Mem -Descending
    }
}
Get-ProcessMemorySummary1 | Sort-Object Mem



Function Get-ProcessMemorySummary2
{
    $Processes = get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName
    foreach($Process in $Processes)
    {
        $Obj = New-Object psobject
        $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Process.Name
        $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Mem -Value ($Process.Group `
             | Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum
        $Obj
    }
}

Get-ProcessMemorySummary2 | Sort-Object Mem

Name                         Mem
----                         ---
Idle                        8192
smss                     1277952
NisSrv                   1536000
ptim                     1765376
ptsrv                    1945600
ONENOTEM                 3014656
rundll32                 3084288
Secure System            3899392
ibtsiva                  4325376
SynTPHelper              4648960
fdlauncher               5128192
ssh-agent                5353472
ibmpmsvc                 5521408
fdhost                   6725632
...

Get-ProcessMemorySummary2 | Sort-Object Mem -Descending

Name                         Mem
----                         ---
iexplore              1890992128
svchost               1115009024
powershell_ise         834617344
RDCMan                 734556160
sqlservr               698155008
Microsoft.Photos       396951552
dwm                    346951680
MsMpEng                201469952
explorer               184778752
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hint: What are you sorting here?

```
foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
    #...
    $Obj | sort Mem -Descending
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Someone showed me a while back that using Add-Member is a resource hog. Using a PSCustomObject gives you potentially tighter code with less redundancy and allows for easy to read sorting.

```
Get-Process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | ForEach-Object {
[array]$objProcesses += [PSCustomObject][ordered] @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Mem = $(($_.Group | Measure-Object  WorkingSet -Sum).Sum)
}
}
Return $objProcesses
```